# How to disable all the magento functions, to keep only the homepage?

Tags: multistore, products, frontend, magento-1.9, multidomain

I have a multistores with one parent domain, and 2 stores on 2 differents domains.
I don't want to sell products on my parent domain, so I would like to disable all the magento functions, and keep only the homepage.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change webserver to nginx so you don't have to touch .htaccess. Then simply don't rewrite to /index.php, put up a static homepage as `index.html` and configure nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name parent.domain.tld;
    root /path/to/document/root;

    location = / {
         index index.html;
    }

    location / {
    return 404;
}
```

Done.

Comment: I think the only thing missing in your code is to exclude the /admin urls so they can still access the backend. +1 anyway, that's a good answer